# Kafka and Zookeeper TLS

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, tls1.2

I am trying to enable TLS for kafka broker exchanges and had a thought regarding Zookeeper TLS. Currently, on Apache Kafka Documentation I cannot see much mentioned about ZK TLS setup (ok, probably because it's a different apache project) and any possible performance impact.

The question is, can I not have the ONLY broker-client and inter-broker exchanges secured? Do I also need to add TLS to zookeeper? Extra security isn't bad, but is it really necessary to it even for zookeeper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zookeeper with TLS is only available in Zookeeper 3.5 which is still in beta. Therefore, Kafka isn't supporting TLS connections to zookeeper yet. Doesn't mean you can't do it but it does mean you won't find much documentation on it and if you run in it on something important, you are putting yourself at risk. In this case, I would say the extra security could hurt.

Comment: That's helpful to know. My only concern was that I was already using solid encryption on my data from server side + I was using TLS and client authentication - seemed like an overkill doing zookeeper too.

Comment: Yeah I'd agree it's a bit overkill

Comment: ZooKeeper has its first stable release of the 3.5.x branch now.
With that, you can setup TLS-encryption between Kafka and ZooKeeper by simply replacing the ZooKeeper, that is bundled with Kafka 2.3.0 with version 3.5.5, and switch on TLS. I have written a mini-howto showing that: https://juplo.de/encrypt-communication-between-kafka-and-zookeeper-with-tls/